# Can I use injected beans as arguments for another class' method?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a hibernate project and I'm moving some logic from a BLL class to a DTO, and I was wondering if it's possible to inject objects into a DTO? The code from the BLL class relied on a lot of imported beans, but when I tried importing them into my DTO object my applicationContext would mess up.

FlightHelper class:

```
public class FlightHelper {

    @Inject
    private InjectedClass injectedClass;

    public void testMethod(Flight flight) {
        ...code here
        flight.getPrice(injectedClass);
    }
}
```

Flight class:

```
public class Flight {
    public void getPrice(InjectedClass injectedClass) {
        ...code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

However, the design is not very nice because you have a very strong interaction between Flight and FlightHelper classes.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but you might want to instead inject them in the other class aswell.